# Scraping text with rvest

Tags: r, web, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape a text item from the following website:
http://www.fangraphs.com/statss.aspx?playerid=639&position=3B
The item I want to scrape is the "3B" from that follows "Position:" near the top of the web page. My attempt below only creates a empty dataset aka:
`character(0)`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
library(rvest)
url="http://www.fangraphs.com/statss.aspx?playerid=10155&position=3B"       
ret <- url %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="content"]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div[2]/text()[4]') %>%
    html_text()

ret
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `xpath`: `//*[@id="content"]/table[1]/tr/td[1]/table/tr[1]/td/div[2]/text()[5]`
It is basically the same as yours, except that it excludes `tbody` tags -not sure why, can't find it documented- and changes the last index to 5.

Result for `playerid=639`: `" 3B"`

(add `%>% trimws()` at the end to get `"3B"`)

Comment: @g gamba Thanks! Wish I knew what the issue was copying that xpath for the future though.